# Put value in parameter using beanshell and jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a question about a very basic script that I wrote,
I just want to get data from DB, put it in a variable using beanshell sampler. 
and in the end of the thread group to create another bean shell and check the value of this variable.

the problem is at saving the data to a variable (var name is before), when I use the props.put command but the value still null.

Can someone please advise?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store a value into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you should amend your code like:

```
vars.put("before", String.valueOf("budgetInt"))
System.out.println("Before is " + vars.get("before"));
```

Once done you should be able to access the defined variable as `${before}` or `${__V(before)}` where required.

If you amend your property setting like:

```
props.put("Before", String.valueOf(budgetInt))
```

You should be also able to access the value as `${__P(Before,)}`

Also consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Comment: Hey dimitry I tried what you suggested and get:   Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List; import redis.clients.jedis.Je . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: valueOf() on undefined variable or class name: string

Comment: `String` needs to start with capital `S`

Comment: `${__P(Before,)}` what should be there after comma?

Answer (score 0):

var before isn't assign and therefore it's null.

You should get value as:

```
var before = props.get("Before");
```